# Best way to compute the following numerical integral?

Tags: numerical-integration

I want to perform

```
NIntegrate[-(2 u)^1000 E^(-2000 u) 1/(1 - 2 u), {u, 0, Infinity}]
```

When I attempt this on my machine, *Mathematica* warns me that

> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections

I am a very pedestrian user of numerical integration, but I am aware that *Mathematica* has different strategies for this purpose. Can anybody recommend me a proper approach to tackle this numerical integral?

Comment: `NIntegrate` cannot integrate stuff that is not purely numerical: you seem to want this integral for some unspecified `N`. Another problem is that `N` is a reserved _Mathematica_ function name. Trying `Integrate[-(2 u)^n E^(-2 n u) 1/(1 - 2 u), {u, 0, Infinity}]` instead, _Mathematica_ tells me after a few seconds that the integral does not converge.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer  corrected

Comment: Since you have a singularity at `u == 1/2`, you need to specify that you want a principal value. The symbolic answer is more useful because you have such crazy huge exponents: `Integrate[-(2 u)^n E^(-2 n u) 1/(1 - 2 u), {u, 0, Infinity}, 
 PrincipalValue -> True]` gives something...

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer I know that I can perform it analytically. I have that. I want a numerical check.

Answer (score 2):

This is how the integrand looks like:

```
GraphicsGrid[
Partition[
Table[Plot[-((2*u)^n/(E^(2*n*u)*(1 - 2*u))), 
          {u, 0.4, 0.6}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {All, {-1, 5}}, MaxRecursion -> 12, 
          PlotLabel -> StringJoin["n = ", ToString[n]]],
{n, 2, 12, 2}], 3], ImageSize -> 600, Spacings -> 0]
```

[image]

It has an asymptote at $u=0.5$. Let's split the integral into two parts excluding the singularity (for illustrative purposes - see also the comment at the end of this post):

```
ε = 0.00001;

int[n_] := 
 NIntegrate[-(2 u)^n E^(-2 n u) 1/(1 - 2 u), {u, 0, 0.5 - ε}] + 
  NIntegrate[-(2 u)^n E^(-2 n u) 1/(1 - 2 u), {u, 0.5 + ε, Infinity}]
```

and

```
ListPlot[Table[{n, int[n]}, {n, 1, 20}], Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[Large]}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"n", "int[n]"}]
```

[image]

`int[20]` is $1.92\cdot 10^{-10}$, and `int[100]` - $1.55\cdot 10^{-45}$. The value `n = 1000` gives a numerical zero.

Those values are the same if obtained with `Integrate` performed with `PrincipalValue -> True` - see [Marius's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130012/best-way-to-computethe-following-numerical-integral/130026#comment351172_130012); in general

```
Normal @ Integrate[-(2 u)^n E^(-2 n u) 1/(1 - 2 u), {u, 0, Infinity}, 
         PrincipalValue -> True]
```

[image]

with a condition `Re[n] >= 0`.

Answer (score 2):

Explicitly listing the singularity at `1/2` gives an error-free result:

```
NIntegrate[-(2 u)^1000 E^(-2000 u) 1/(1 - 2 u), {u, 0, 1/2, Infinity},
 MaxRecursion -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 16, 
 Method -> "PrincipalValue"]
(*  6.705858148612409*10^-437  *)
```

It is stable under increasing `WorkingPrecision`, `PrecisionGoal` and `MinRecursion`. 
***Update:*** It agrees with the following symbolic result:

```
int = Integrate[-(2 u)^1000 E^(-2000 u) 1/(1 - 2 u), u];
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500},
 N[Limit[int, u -> Infinity] - Limit[int, u -> 0], 16]
 ]
(*  6.705858148607688*10^-437  *)
```

The agreement between the numeric result above and the exact result
improves as the `WorkingPrecision` increases.  So this now seems to be the correct result. (Compare with the result below.)

---

*Original:*
The symbolic result of [Marius Ladegård Meyer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130012/best-way-to-compute-the-following-numerical-integral#comment351172_130012) is somewhat different from the answer above:

```
val = Integrate[-(2 u)^n E^(-2 n u) 1/(1 - 2 u), {u, 0, Infinity}, 
  PrincipalValue -> True];
N[Limit[val, n -> 1000], 8]
(* 1.26877823*10^-438 + 0.*10^-447 I  *)
```

Apparently this symbolic result is erroneous.